# to replace black portion of an image, with any other image: in matlab

Tags: image, matlab

i have an image named imageA...imageA has some portion colored black.
now i want to replace this Black portion of the imageA with the pixels of imageB , in such a way that  location of portion is same in other image.

like if the position of black pixel in imageA=(10,15) , than this black pixel should be replaced with the pixel at the location (10,15) in imageB .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Logical Indexing.](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/)

```
zeropixels = imageA == 0
imageA(zeropixels) = imageB(zeropixels)
```

You might need some extra error checking code to ensure that the logical matrix `zeropixels` is valid for indexing imageB.

Comment: but it dosent replace black portion totally,, some black portion(in form of dots and lines) remains there>?

Comment: Some of the black pixels must be a little brighter than zero.  Try something like `blackpixels = imageA < 5`.